# How to fix Software-center in linux Elementary OS with error: "gi.RepositoryError: Typelib file for namespace 'GdkPixbuf', version '2.0' not found"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, package, apt-get

I get the following error output Whenever I run in terminal: $ software-center

```
Traceback (most recent call last) 
File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 25, in <module> from
 gi.repository import Gtk, GObject
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/importer.py", line 67, in load_module
dynamic_module._load()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 294, in _load
self._introspection_module = get_introspection_module(self._namespace)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 273, in get_introspection_module
module = IntrospectionModule(namespace, version)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 122, in __init__repository.require(namespace, version)
gi.RepositoryError: Typelib file for namespace 'GdkPixbuf', version '2.0' not found
```

Answer (score 2):

After hours of research I get software-center opening after the following command:

```
export GI_TYPELIB_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/girepository-1.0
```

(In my case the above command was like this, but you might inform above /path/to/my/typelib_dir python my_prog.py instead, if your folders are located in a different path).